# android i`importantForA11y=false` vs. `setConentDescription=@null` vs. `focusable=false`

Tags: android, accessibility, focusable, android-a11y

I can see `importantForA11y` is for `minSdk=6+`

But why would one have to use it, if they can just use `setConentDescription=@null`?

What is the difference between `importantForA11y=false` vs. `setConentDescription=@null` vs. `focusable=false`

Answer (score 2):

`ImportantForAccessibility=false` is used to hide any element from the accessibility tree, including buttons, content etc.

`contentDescription=null` is only useful for things like images (there may be other items I can't think of) that you want to hide as otherwise the Accessibility Tree will do it's best to find a suitable name for an item.

A prime example would be an `ImageButton` - if you use `contentDescription=null` then it will announce 'button' and the destination / button text. If you use `ImportantForAccessibility=false` it would hide that item completely from the accessibility tree.

The best analogy I can come up with (if you are familiar with Web Standards) is that `contentDescription` is like an `alt` attribute or `aria-labelledby` attribute and `ImportantForAccessibility=false` is similar to `aria-hidden="true"`.

With regards to `focusable=false`, this should be used for things like `ImageView`s, it should always be used in conjunction with `importantForAccessibility=false` (or `importantForAccessibility="no"`) to ensure an item that is purely decorative is completely removed from the accessibility tree.

There are probably some edge cases I can't think of so above all, test it with `TalkBack` or a similar screen reader.